# Нужно реализовать php-скрипт на сервере под Unix

Tags: php, unix

Нужно реализовать php-скрипт на сервере под Unix, который бы выводил каждые 15 секунд фразу «Hello».
После вывода «Hello» скрипт всегда завершает работу. Напишите этот скрипт и пожалуйста, пошагово расскажите, что нужно
сделать, чтобы выполнялись исходные условия.
У меня мало опыта в этом деле, будет очень интересно почитать ваши посты и разобраться, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Куда выводить ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Да, Вы правы, скрипт завершает свою работу. Именно поэтому у нас есть 2 пути:

1. Планировщик на сервере (cron). Заставлять его по какому-либо интервалу запрашивать скрипт
2. Добавить в страницу мета тег `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="15" />`. Получается, что она будет обновляться каждые 15 секунд, что и нужно. Естественно, необходимо, чтобы данная страница была открыта у вас в браузере

Comment: А что будет выводить этот скрипт в первом варианте? И кому?

Comment: Не важно кому, хоть в логи. В задании ничего не сказано про то, куда - в браузер\файл

Comment: в какие конкретно логи? Если в задании не сказано конкретно, то наверное стоит сначала уточнить, перед тем как ответ писать?

Comment: Товарищ минусующий, я написал возможные пути решения проблемы для разных случаев. Если Вам нечего добавить к ответу по теме, для чего ставить минусы?

Answer (score 0):

я так понимаю это какое-то задание и вам нужно чтобы кто-то решил его...

Создайте hello_script.php

```
<?php
while (true) {
    echo "Hello\n";
    sleep(15); // Приостановка выполнения на 15 секунд
}
?>
```

в терминале

```
php hello_script.php
```