# php скрипт на сервере под Unix

Tags: php, unix

Нужно реализовать php скрипт под Unix. Который бы в промежутках, а именно в 15 секунд. Выводил бы фразу Hello
Использую этот $php -r 'while(true){ echo "Hello"\n"; sleep(15);}
По моему скрипту висит бесконечный цикл с таймаутом 15сек
Как это исправить? Нужно под сервер Unix

Comment: ок, мой код работатает:) так а что не нравиться?

Comment: hestill - А я вас помню. Вы уже писали этот вопрос 25-го марта: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1260497/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-php-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-unix И тут какая то ерунда: вы бы потратили на 15 секунд больше времени и написали, что именно не так с прошлым решением. А то не все кидаются помогать по второму разу, ну, это как с мальчиком, который кричал "Волки, волки!"

Comment: Условия задачи не выполняются, т.к. скрипт не завершает свою работу, а висит в бесконечном цикле

Comment: А чем висение скрипта в беспонечном цикле нарушает первоначальное условие задачи? Он фразу выводит? выводит. Тогда напишите, что вы хотите, чтобы скрипт ЗАПУСКАЛСЯ каждые 15 секунд ЗАНОВО и выводил такую то фразу

Comment: Да, чтобы он запускался каждые 15 секунд и выводил фразу, все верно

Comment: Отлично. Мы продвинулись. Но тут беда... а куда он должен выводить эту фразу? Когда скрипт висит в беспонечном цикле - то у него есть "терминал", связанный с этим процессом. Вы хотите, чтобы у вас раз в 15 секунд в системе ВОЗБУЖДАЛСЯ (прости меня, госсподи, за такой оборот речи) процесс. А куда ему ввод - вывод делать то? И еще - откуда ему брать переменные окружения?

Comment: Мой диагноз - да опять таки простят меня все - что Вы, hestill, формулируете часть вопроса, в надежде что потом сможете предложенное решение переделать под свои цели. Это - нормально. Но Вам могут дать гораздо более ценный совет, если Вы напишиете, что Вы на самом деле делаете. Может, Вам нужен элементарный cron. А может, вам надо написать простой скрипт, который будет висеть в бесконечном цикле и раз в 15 сек fork'аться

Comment: Суть в чем, просто вывод фразы, каждые 15 секунд на сервер. 
Тот код что вы мне написали я думаю можно модернизировать через рефреш скорее всего, но я не знаю как правильно им воспользоваться.

Comment: Фраза исчезает и появляется каждые 15 секунд, через крон не получится это сделать потому что там интервал на сколько мне известно, минимум 1 минута

Comment: Не хочу делать вид, что я самый умный, но, нет такого "вывода на сервер". От этого все и бесятся. Потому что непотятно, что это такое. Прикрепите картинку, пожалуйста? На которой показано то место, куда вы хотите, чтобы выводилась фраза

Comment: http://vam.in.ua/index.php/it/15-other-posix/82-cron-nseconds-tasks.html - первая ссылка из гугла, как заставить крон работать чаще, чем раз в минуту. https://habr.com/ru/post/148688/ - как fork'аться в php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запустить повторяющийся скрипт при включении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543427/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Это консольной скрипт, который отрабатывает именно на сервере, без браузера. Так понятнее ?

Comment: Если вы понимаете как сделать вывод через каждые 15 секунд фразу, вы мне очень поможете

Comment: `$ while :; do php -r "echo 'hello\n'"; sleep 15; done` — все условия выполнены: 1. скрипт на php. 2. скрипт запускается раз в 15 секунд и завершает работу. 3. скрипт выводит строку `"hello"`.

Comment: чтобы пользователь получил уведомление о комментарии, надо упомянуть его так `@имя` (трёх уникальных первых букв будет достаточно, но вообще после ввода `@` сразу предлагаются варианты подстаноки)

Comment: `как сделать вывод` — вывод **куда**? вас же ясно об этом спросили. и уже не один раз. ответьте, пожалуйста. всего один раз. не надо повторять вопрос на разные лады. просто дайте ответ на уточняющий вопрос.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin

Comment: Это консольной скрипт, который отрабатывает именно на сервере, без браузера.

Comment: @aleksandr мне нужно чтобы после завершения работы скрипта, был старт скрипта ещё раз и так каждые 15 секунд

Comment: вы вновь повторили то, что уже писали несколько раз, но так и не ответили на уточняющий вопрос: «куда скрипт должен вывести сообщение?». давайте я для надёжности повторю ещё раз: «скрипт куда должен вывести сообщение?». и ещё раз, чтобы вы заметили: «сообщение скрипт куда должен вывести?».

Comment: @aleksandr В консоль, скрипт должен вывести в консоль

Comment: предложенный выше [вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266392/php-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-unix?noredirect=1#comment2227610_1266392) полностью удовлетворяет и этому условию.